# How to create and seed associated models in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a `Comment` model which `belongsTo` a `User` model. This is how I'm creating it:

```
var log_status = console.log;
var u = require("lodash");

models.sequelize.sync({
  force: true,
  logging: log_status, 
}).then(function() {
  return models.Users.bulkCreate([
    { first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith" },
    { first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Carter" },
  ], {logging: log_status});
}).then(function() { 
    return models.Users.findAll({logging: log_status}); 
}).then(function(users) {
  user_ids = u.object(u.map(users, function (x){ 
    return [x.first_name + " " x.last_name, x.id];
  }));
  return models.Comment.bulkCreate([
    { UserId: user_ids["John Smith"], body: "This is a comment" },
    { UserId: user_ids["John Smith"], body: "This is another comment" },
    { UserId: user_ids["Jane Carter"], body: "This is my comment" },
  ], {logging: log_status});
}).then(function(comments) {
  comment_ids = u.object(u.map(comments, function (x){ 
    return [x.first_name + " " x.last_name, x.id];
  }));

  // ...
});
```

Because I'm using sqlite as my database, I have to use `findAll` to get the ids because [only PostgreSQL and MySQL return the primary ids after `bulkCreate`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2630). This works, but I would like to know if there is a better way to populate associated models.